# Need UI testing && analyzing tool for Windows

Tags: c#, windows, user-interface, functional-testing

I have very little experience with Windows platform and I really need a tool to test my application from the UI side. Quick i-net search make me completely baffled, so any help is highly appreciated.

Key requirements:

1. Can fire user-driven events (such as click on specific place, drag'n'drop, text input)
2. Can capture screenshots (e.g. on failure)
3. Can analyze screenshots (sometimes application fires random events and creates pop-ups, needs to intercept and handle such situations).
   Maybe I can delegate this to some third-party process?
4. Can create reports and store them in file system.

Application itself is written on C#, but it doesn't matter, right?

Comment: "sometimes application fires random events" ? :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you're developing with WPF (or even WinForms), I'd give [Microsoft UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx) a shot. In conjunction with MSUnit or NUnit it allows easy and programmable UI tests.

Answer (score 0):

Nunit is good for functional & Logic testing, its 3rd Party and free to Install. But I dont think it will cover capturing Screenshots etc.